# Eliminate JavaScript "screen flash" when applying JS to "Purecss.io" CSS menus?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I eliminate the "screen flash" by delaying the display of these menu's until after the JavaScript is loaded and applied to the menu elements?

I'm using Dropdown Menu's from: http://purecss.io/menus/

"Adding dropdowns to menus requires the use of JavaScript using their method."

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Untitled Document
    </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo-horizontal-menu">
    <ul id="std-menu-items">
        <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="#">Flickr</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Other</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="pure-menu-heading">More from Yahoo!</li>
                <li class="pure-menu-separator"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Flickr</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Answers</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Even More</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Horoscopes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">OMG</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
YUI({
    classNamePrefix: 'pure'
}).use('gallery-sm-menu', function (Y) {

    var horizontalMenu = new Y.Menu({
        container         : '#demo-horizontal-menu',
        sourceNode        : '#std-menu-items',
        orientation       : 'horizontal',
        hideOnOutsideClick: false,
        hideOnClick       : false
    });

    horizontalMenu.render();
    horizontalMenu.show();

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic work-around to avoid screen flash when you're waiting for javascript to apply some type of formatting or create some content is to set up a CSS rule or inline style that makes the content that would flash be initially not visible.

Depending upon the particular circumstances, you can use either `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`.  If your content is already the correct size but just need some styling, then you may want to use `visibility: hidden` because that will allow everything to lay out properly (so no content will jump or move when you make it visible).  If your content isn't the right size yet, then you may want to go with `display: none` to avoid layout it out once, then having the size change when the final styling is applied via JS and then having it lay out again.

---

In your code, if you just add this to your CSS:

```
#demo-horizontal-menu {
    visbility: hidden;
}
```

Or alternatively, you could apply an inline style in the HTML:

```
<div id="demo-horizontal-menu" style="visbility: hidden;">
```

Then, there will be no menu flash as things load.  The `.show()` method seems to already take care of making the menu visible for you after it's been fully initialized.

Working demo with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XT259/